# How to animate from length 0 -> 100 but remove animation from 100 -> 0

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I have this timeline

```
<div class="timeline-wrapper">
 <div class="timeline-item">
   <div class="timeline-loaded" style="width: 100%"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline-item">
   <div class="timeline-loaded" style="width: 100%"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline-item">
   <div class="timeline-loaded" style="width: 83%"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So the last item goes up from to 84, 85 etc. but when i reset the timeline i want to have all the items style width: 0% but then it has the transition animation so u see that it goes to 0 but it needs to go to 0 instantly and smoothly fill from 0 to 100%.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Please show us any relevant JS and CSS (are you using CSS animations for example?) and put enough code into your question for us to see the problem and in a way that we can run the snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your question what I got is you need some progressbar. You can refer to this.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp

```
var i = 0;
function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically it will modify width of your class. If you need more help on this please elaborate your requirement more with jsfiddle or any same.